# Don't know how to fix "The non-generic type 'ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments"?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm trying to read a text file into an ArrayList.  If I include  in this line: " `ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();`", then I get the non-generic error, but if I remove it then I get this error on the return line:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace mhpreader
{
    internal class NewBaseType
    { 
        public ArrayList messages = new ArrayList();

        internal NewMhpReader ReadMessages()
        {
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
    internal class NewMhpReader : NewBaseType
    {
        private string _FilePath;

        public NewMhpReader(string FilePath)
        {
            this._FilePath = FilePath;
        }

        private string line;

        public NewMhpReader[] ReadMessages(string nMessages)
        {
             ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
             //List<TextReader> messages = new List<string>;
             using (StreamReader stre = new StreamReader(_FilePath))
             {
                   while ((line = stre.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                         messages.Add(line);
                         Console.WriteLine(messages);
                   }
             }
             return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) instead of `ArrayList`, which is outdated. See [the remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks) on the `ArrayList` documentation.

Comment: I switched messages to be a List<string>, but I'm still getting this error, on the return messages; line "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'"

Comment: You're not returning the type that you told your method to expect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to help you out a bit:

1. I would remove ArrayList as others have suggested and replace it with List
2. your List TextReader  needs to be List string
3. Change your Console.WriteLine(messages) to Console.WriteLine(line)
4. make sure you are including the Generics namespace in your usings (for List<>).
5. make sure you return the correct type of List string. This is the one that is causing the compiler error you are seeing.

   ```
            public List<string> ReadMessages(string nMessages)
            {
                List<string> messages = new List<string>;
                using (StreamReader stre = new StreamReader(_FilePath))
                    {
                        while ((line = stre.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            messages.Add(line);
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                return messages;
            }
   ```